# An array of objects as a property for a User Control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a user control in a Windows Forms Application that will do some magic when I click on its button depending on some info from an object that I give it at design-time. I want an array with objects in this class (`UserControl`) and I want the .name field of these classes to be shown as a list in the property window in the designer.

```
static class AllThings
{
    static OneThing blah;
    static OneThing hurr;
    static OneThing durr;

    static AllThings()
    {
        blah = new OneThing("name");
        hurr = new OneThing("name");
        durr = new OneThing("name");
    }
```

So if I have this array

```
OneThing[] arrayOfAllThings = 
{
    blah,
    hurr,
    durr
};
```

Is there any way to do so that I will see a list of all the OneThing-objects and be able to click on one to set a variable to that instance?

Comment: Web? WPF? Winforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, There is. Visual studio will automatically handle array properties for you.

Here is a test I've made:

Here is the `OneThing` class:

```
public class OneThing
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Here is the UserControl's code (without the designer code, but that's just out of the box...)

```
public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public OneThing[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how it looks like at design time:

[image]

[image]

[image]